# Filtering a logfile in shell into a variable with using a regrex

Tags: shell, jenkins, filter, echo, logfile

I have a logfile from Jenkins named $log_file in a shell.
But I just need a little part of the logfile to use it on a wiki.
With: `echo $log_file | sed '\(\\[INFO\\]\) \+\(\.|\\n\)*\(\\+---------\\+\)'`
I tried to filter it, but it didn't work.

The regex is: `(\[INFO\]) \+(.|\n)*(\+---------\+\n)`

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question. Please do add samples of input and expected output for better understanding of your question too in your question, thank you.

Comment: The text doens't matter, because the regex is working. I just need a way in shell to use the regex on a text and save the result in a variable.